# Wonder plugin slider not working in internet explorer

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress version is `4.7.4`

I installed lucid theme `version 2.5` .

I installed wonder plugin slider `Version 4.2` from [here](https://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-slider/)

my slider in not working in internet explorer i don't know why.

I tried to deactivate all other plugins but problem is same, I tried so hard to find the solution but i can't find any solution. What should i do? any suggestion?

Comment: Some things don't work for every browser. Have you searched if that plugin is supported by IE? Plus, do you have any errors in console?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos It's fully responsive, works on iPhone, iPad, Android, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera and Internet Explorer 7/8/9/10/11.

Comment: In which version of explorer it doesn't work?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I am using IE v 11

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I already tried that too

Comment: I think the best thing you could do is create a thread on the specific's plugin developers..